# Simple Auction system in C - tips?

Tags: c, file

I wrote this program in C for a small auction system using information gathered from a file. The auction system should store bids, apply starting bids/minimum increase bids to a list, and then display the results via a menu system. I believe I have achieved the objective of the project, but I am now attempting to simplify my code.

I am unsure if my code is at all correct, or if there is an easier way to layout the information using less code. Any tips would also be very much appreciated! Thank you for your time.

The input file looks like this

```
500 40
100 20
20 7
300 55
700 120
```

Where the first number is the "Auction Starting Bid"

and the second number is the "Auction Minimum Increase"

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

//int main
int main() {

//open input text
    FILE * ifp;
    ifp = fopen("input.txt", "r");

    printf("Welcome to the Silent Auction\n");
    printf("\nPlease make a selection from the following:\n");

    int number = 1;
    int starting_bid1 = 0;
    int starting_bid2 = 0;
    int starting_bid3 = 0;
    int starting_bid4 = 0;
    int starting_bid5 = 0;

    int au1_start, au1_min, au2_start, au2_min, au3_start, au3_min, au4_start, au4_min, au5_start, au5_min;
    char choice [20];

    fscanf(ifp, "%d %d", &au1_start, &au1_min);
    fscanf(ifp, "%d %d", &au2_start, &au2_min);
    fscanf(ifp, "%d %d", &au3_start, &au3_min);
    fscanf(ifp, "%d %d", &au4_start, &au4_min);
    fscanf(ifp, "%d %d", &au5_start, &au5_min);

    printf("\nView Auctions [VIEW]\nBid on an Auction [BID]\nClose Auctions [CLOSE]\n");
    scanf("%s", &choice);

    if (strcmp(choice, "VIEW", "view", "View") == 0) {

            printf("\nNumber    Current Bid    Minimum Increase\n");

            if (starting_bid1 < au1_start){
                printf("1         $%d             $%d\n", starting_bid1, au1_start);
            }
            else{
                printf("1         $%d             $%d\n", starting_bid1, au1_min);
            }

            if (starting_bid2 < au2_start){
                printf("2         $%d             $%d\n", starting_bid2, au2_start);
            }
            else{
                printf("2         $%d             $%d\n", starting_bid2, au2_min);
            }

            if (starting_bid3 < au3_start){
                printf("3         $%d             $%d\n", starting_bid3, au3_start);
            }
            else{
                printf("3         $%d             $%d\n", starting_bid3, au3_min);
            }

            if (starting_bid4 < au4_start){
                printf("4         $%d             $%d\n", starting_bid4, au4_start);
            }
            else{
                printf("4         $%d             $%d\n", starting_bid4, au4_min);
            }

            if (starting_bid5 < au5_start){
                printf("5         $%d             $%d\n", starting_bid5, au5_start);
            }
            else{
                printf("5         $%d         D    $%d\n", starting_bid5, au5_min);
            }
        }

    else if (strcmp(choice, "BID", "bid", "Bid") == 0) {
            printf("\nWhich auction would you like to bid on?\n");
            scanf("%d", &number);

                switch (number) {
                    case 1:
                        printf("The minimum bid is $%d.\n", au1_start);
                        printf("How much would you like to bid?\n");
                        scanf("%d", &starting_bid1);
                        if (starting_bid1 < au1_start){
                            printf("Sorry, that bid is not high enough.\n");
                        }
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        printf("The minimum bid is $%d.\n", au2_start);
                        printf("How much would you like to bid?\n");
                        scanf("%d", &starting_bid2);
                        if (starting_bid2 < au2_start){
                            printf("Sorry, that bid is not high enough.\n");
                        }
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        printf("The minimum bid is $%d.\n", au3_start);
                        printf("How much would you like to bid?\n");
                        scanf("%d", &starting_bid3);
                        if (starting_bid3 < au3_start){
                            printf("Sorry, that bid is not high enough.\n");
                        }
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        printf("The minimum bid is $%d.\n", au4_start);
                        printf("How much would you like to bid?\n");
                        scanf("%d", &starting_bid4);
                        if (starting_bid4 < au4_start){
                            printf("Sorry, that bid is not high enough.\n");
                        }
                    case 5:
                        printf("The minimum bid is $%d.\n", au5_start);
                        printf("How much would you like to bid?");
                        scanf("%d", &starting_bid5);
                        if (starting_bid5 < au5_start){
                            printf("Sorry, that bid is not high enough.\n");
                        }
                    default:
                        printf("\n");
                }
            }
    else if (strcmp(choice, "CLOSE", "close", "Close") == 0) {
            if (starting_bid1 >= au1_start){
                printf("\nAuction 1 sold for %d.\n", starting_bid1);
            }
            else{
                printf("\nAuction 1 did not sell.\n");
            }

            if (starting_bid2 >= au2_start){
                printf("Auction 2 sold for %s.\n", starting_bid2);
            }
            else{
                printf("Auction 2 did not sell.\n");
            }

            if (starting_bid3 >= au3_start){
                printf("Auction 3 sold for %s.\n", starting_bid3);
            }
            else{
                printf("Auction 3 did not sell.\n");
            }
            if (starting_bid4 >= au4_start){
                printf("Auction 4 sold for %s.\n", starting_bid4);
            }
            else{
                printf("Auction 4 did not sell.\n");
            }

            if (starting_bid5 >= au5_start){
                printf("Auction 5 sold for %s.\n", starting_bid5);
            }
            else{
                printf("Auction 5 did not sell.\n");
            }
    }
    else{
        printf("\nPlease choose either VIEW, BID, or CLOSE.\n");
    }

// formatting
    printf("\n");

//close file
    fclose(ifp);

//return main
return 0;
}
```

**Bold represents user input**

The final product should look like:

```
Welcome to the Silent Auction 

Please make a selection from the following: 
View Auctions [VIEW] 
Bid on an Auction [BID] 
Close Auctions [CLOSE]
```

**VIEW**

```
Number Current Bid Minimum Increase 
1  $0.00  $500.0 
2  $0.00  $100.00 
3  $0.00  $20.00 
4  $0.00  $300.00 
5  $0.00  $700.00 

Please make a selection from the following: 
View Auctions [VIEW] 
Bid on an Auction [BID] 
Close Auctions [CLOSE]
```

**BID**

```
Which auction would you like to bid on?
```

**3**

```
The minimum bid is $20.00. 
How much would you like to bid?
```

**21**

```
Please make a selection from the following: 
View Auctions [VIEW] 
Bid on an Auction [BID] 
Close Auctions [CLOSE]
```

**CLOSE**

```
Auction 1 did not sell. 
Auction 2 did not sell. 
Auction 3 sold for $21.00! 
Auction 4 did not sell. 
Auction 5 did not sell.
```

Comment: Please narrow your post down to something relevant.

Comment: The "accepted" answer is: it's missing a comma.

Answer (score 3):

You're missing a comma:

```
fscanf(ifp, "%d %d", &au1_start &au1_min);
```

should be

```
fscanf(ifp, "%d %d", &au1_start, &au1_min);
```

Evidently the compiler parsed it as `(&au1_start) & au1_min`, with the second `&`
being interpreted as the binary `&` (bitwise AND) operator, thus the warning, due
to mismatched data types.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your question on whether there's an easier way to lay out the information using less code, the most obvious solution is to make arrays out of `starting_bid`, `au_start` and `au_min`.  Then, instead of having a separate if-else or case statement for each of the 5 auctions, you can have a single statement which indexes the array using the auction number.

Comment: Ahh, unfortunately I have yet to study Arrays, but I will research them and apply your suggestions to attempt to simplify the code. Thanks!

Comment: after many attempts to implement arrays it seem I could not get the program to work, but for the future I will attempt to do this